# R:ggplotly stack bar graph shows wrong label

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(plotly)
dat<-data.frame(A=letters[1:5],B=seq(10,50,10),C=seq(60,100,10))
ggplotly(dat %>% melt(id.vars="A") %>% ggplot(aes(A,value,fill=variable)) +geom_bar(stat = "identity"))
```

The graph gets the data correctly plotted but the label gives wrong value for the variable B when hovered over the bar. Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: if you add text to your ggplot() it should work. e.g. gplot(aes(A,value,fill=variable, text=value))

Comment: @MLavoie can you help me to correct the value stated for Type B,instead of adding new text for the label.

Comment: not sure if you could do better but try pp <- style(p, hoverinfo="none", traces= 1:2); style(pp, hoverinfo="name+y", traces= 1:2)